# Symfony2 error ObjectIdentity is already associated with an ACL

Tags: symfony, acl

I've searched around and here in SO, but I didn't find a valid answer, in fact there few questions about this error with even fewer responses.
So here is my problem: i have a page in an application through which the admin can reset the ACL to the defaults.
It's been working fine everywhere until now on a single machine, when it tries to create permissions to Admin on the Store entity, it throws the error 'ObjectIdentity is already associated with an ACL'.
The problem seems to be that the AclProvider->findAcl() function can't find any acl record for the Store entity class (even if there are both on acl_classes and object_identities), so it goes for creating a new one, then fails because, as the error says, the object has already an acl record.

If I search directly on the db

```
SELECT * FROM acl_classes where class_type = 'Espresso2\\PimBundle\\Entity\\Store';
```

1 record found: 
75  Espresso2\PimBundle\Entity\Store

`SELECT * FROM acl_object_identities where class_id=75;`

1 record found: 
580     75  store   1

Here is the code

### Custom ACL creator (resets all existing ACLs to the defaults)

```
//All permissions to ROLE_ADMIN on Store objects
$aclProvider = $this->service_container->get('security.acl.provider');
$objectIdentity = new ObjectIdentity('store', 'Espresso2\\PimBundle\\Entity\\Store');
$acl = $this->pimacl->findOrCreateAcl($objectIdentity, 1);
```

### FindOrCreateAcl function

```
    public function findOrCreateAcl($objectIdentity,$reset=0){

    $aclProvider = $this->service_container->get('security.acl.provider');
    $acl=null;
    try{
        $acl=$aclProvider->findAcl($objectIdentity);

    }catch(AclNotFoundException $e){
        $acl = $aclProvider->createAcl($objectIdentity);
    }

    if($reset==1){
        $acl=$this->deleteOldClassAcl($acl);
    }

    return $acl;
}
```

nothing special here, and in fact works well, except for one single machine where it fails; it must be for some missing or non matching record on some tables, but I can't figure where.

Anybody has tips or clues ?

Thx in advance

Marco

Comment: which version of sf2 are you using?

Comment: I'm using 2.0.12, unfortunately upgrade is not an option, for now